# Getting the "Ambiguous use of 'json'" error

Tags: swift

I have this struct

```
public struct QubitDisriptionInfo {
    public let id: String?
    public let popupId: String?
    public let journeyOrigins: String?
    public let journeyDestinations: String?
    public let departureDateFrom: String?
    public let departureDateTo: String?
    public let departureTimeFrom: String?
    public let departureTimeTo: String?
    public let titleCopy: String?
    public let bodyCopy: String?
    public let primaryKey: String?
}

extension QubitDisriptionInfo: JSONObjectConvertible {
    public init(jsonDictionary: JSONDictionary) throws {
        let notifications = jsonDictionary.json(atKeyPath: "data.notifications") as! [[String: String]] // Getting error here
        let notification = notifications.first!
        id = notification.json(atKeyPath: "id") as! String
        popupId = notification.json(atKeyPath: "popup-id") as! String
        journeyOrigins = notification.json(atKeyPath: "journey-origins") as! String
        journeyDestinations = notification.json(atKeyPath: "journey-destinations") as! String
        departureDateFrom = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-date-from") as! String
        departureDateTo = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-date-to") as! String
        departureTimeFrom = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-time-from") as! String
        departureTimeTo = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-time-to") as! String
        titleCopy = notification.json(atKeyPath: "title-copy") as! String
        bodyCopy = notification.json(atKeyPath: "body-copy") as! String
        primaryKey = notification.json(atKeyPath: "primary-key") as! String
    }
}
```

I have different implementations on `.json(atKeyPath: )`, I think the compiler is confused which one of these methods I am trying to use. How do I let the compiler know I want to use a specific one?

Below is the JSON I am trying to decode.

```
{
    "data": {
        "notifications": [
            {
                "id": "118",
                "popup-id": "3",
                "journey-origins": "EUS",
                "journey-destinations": "MAN",
                "departure-date-from": "20230226",
                "departure-date-to": "20230226",
                "departure-time-from": "1900",
                "departure-time-to": "2130",
                "title-copy": "Busy trains expected",
                "body-copy": "Due to the EFL Cup Final at Wembley, trains from Manchester to London in the morning and returning north in the evening are expected to be very busy with football fans. Trains showing 'sold out' are likely to be at full capacity. If you're not heading to the game, we recommend travelling outside of these periods - heading south after 12:00 or heading north before 19:00 is expected to be quieter.",
                "primary-key": "EUS-MAN"
            },
//More Notifications
]}}}
```

Comment: How did you defined `.json(atKeyPath: )`? You might use a Generic? Like `JSONDecoder` does( `func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type,from: Self.Input) throws -> T where T : Decodable`? Something like `Something like: `func json<T>(_ type: T, atKeyPath: String) -> T`?` Also, any reason why you don't use `Codable`?

Comment: @Larme, I the reason I didn’t use codable is that most of the other parts of the app make requests using strut rs as above, (legacy) and I want to keep the structure the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick research and tried the [package](https://github.com/lucianomarisi/JSONUtilities) you're using myself.

```
let notifications = jsonDictionary.json(atKeyPath: "data.notifications") as! [[String: String]]
```

This is weird because there are more than one implementation of `json(atKeyPath:)` that can be satisfied the way you're calling it. You have to be a bit more specific.

On top of that you're trying to force cast the ambiguos result to `[[String: String]]`, which doesn't really make sense.

```
public init(jsonDictionary: JSONDictionary) throws {
        let notifications: [JSONDictionary]
        do {
            notifications = try jsonDictionary.json(atKeyPath: "data.notifications")
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
        let notification = notifications.first!
        id = notification.json(atKeyPath: "id")
        popupId = notification.json(atKeyPath: "popup-id")
        journeyOrigins = notification.json(atKeyPath: "journey-origins")
        journeyDestinations = notification.json(atKeyPath: "journey-destinations")
        departureDateFrom = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-date-from")
        departureDateTo = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-date-to")
        departureTimeFrom = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-time-from")
        departureTimeTo = notification.json(atKeyPath: "departure-time-to")
        titleCopy = notification.json(atKeyPath: "title-copy")
        bodyCopy = notification.json(atKeyPath: "body-copy")
        primaryKey = notification.json(atKeyPath: "primary-key")
    }
```

You probably are looking to something like this as a result.

`jsonDictionary.json(atKeyPath: "data.notifications")` can be called without any compilation error, since he knows the `json(atKeyPath:)` implementation to call, inferred by the type of the constant we're assigning the result to (`[JSONDIctionary]`).

Last, but not least, you can remove any other forced cast you had in the next lines of code. They are all inferred in the same way the first `json(atKeyPath:)` call is.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It gets rid of the `Ambiguous use of json` but I am unsure how the data will be stored, will it be of type `String?` ? Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, a `String?`. All next calls of `json(atKeyPath:)` are calling `public func json<T: JSONRawType>(atKeyPath keyPath: Key) -> T?`.
If you check the implementation, it's going to return a `String` value if there's an actual `String`, or nil if it isn't.